# sharepoint object model itemadding eventreceiver

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to add a event receiver on a list for itemadding.  I have a field called EmployeeName people picker from which i need to get userprofile of that particular employee on item adding and trying to get EmployeeNo auto updated from userprofile.

I using as below: but not working

```
 public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdding(properties);

            UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);

            UserProfile myProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(item["EmployeeName"].ToString());



            if (myProfile["EmployeeNo"].Value != null)
            {

                properties.AfterProperties["EmployeeNo"] = (myProfile["EmployeeNo"]).ToString();

            }


            item.Update();

        }
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you use the correct *internal* column names. 
Where do you get "item" from? Try using properties.ListItem instead.
Don't call properties.ListItem.update() (or item.update() in your code).

Comment: that doesn't work..is it that i have to bring **GetUserProfile(Domain\Username)** like that if so how to get Account name from the field that has been entered as **EmployeeName**

Comment: you should get the employee name with properties.ListItem["EmployeeName"] if "EmployeeName" is the internal name of the field.

Comment: yes i did that..is it a correct way when i am fetching the userprofile based on EmployeeName of which item is not yet added in the itemadding event.